# How to keep asking for user input until the input is empty?

Tags: java

I want to make a while loop so that whenever a user inputs a blank input, it will re-ask the question until it is not empty. So far, I have this:

```
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (//user input is not blank) {

            System.out.print("Enter id: ");
            int id = scn.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            String last_name = scn.next();

            System.out.print("Enter phone: ");
            String first_name = scn.next();

            scn.close();
            break;
        }
```

i'm pretty sure i'm over thinking this but i'm not sure of the syntax or the functions.

Comment: You should also read about exceptions.  The Scanner will throw exceptions on input being incorrect (like when the user enters something that can't be parsed into an integer).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should expect user to type say Quit/quit to quit rather than empty string.
2. You should close scanner out of loop without break.
3. You should use `do...while` loop instead if `while` loop. Something like:

   ```
   do {
      ...
      exit = scn.next();
   } while (!exit.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
   scn.close();
   ```